# Tooltips not working in fullcalendar when i use bootstrap css

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar, mdbootstrap, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to show tooltips in my fullcalendar app. But if i include bootstrap.css it isn't working. When i run code without it, everything is working.

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [
    {
      title: 'My Event',
      start: '2010-01-01',
      description: 'This is a cool event'
    }
    // more events here
  ],
  eventRender: function(info) {
    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
      title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'hover',
      container: 'body'
    });
  }
});
```

with this example code from Fullcalendar.io page and bootstrap.min.css is excluded everything is working.

edit: I forgot to add that i'm using also mdboostrap.css

Edit: Link to Codepen showing the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqKvYv. If you delete twitter-bootstrap from CSS options tooltip is showing

Comment: Most likely there's a conflict in the CSS rules. Which tooltip library are you using? If you check the DOM with the dev tools inspector you'll be able to see which rules are causing the problem and remove/amend them

Comment: i'm using popper.min.js and tooltip.min.js both download from popper.js.org. Dev tool shows nothing.

Comment: I agree with @RoryMcCrossan There can be conflicts with CSS files

Comment: but which one, because in inspector tool is nothing

Comment: "not working" means what? Nothing is displayed? Or the display is incorrect somehow? Please create us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can try and trace it.

Comment: here is example [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WqKvYv) - tooltip is not showing. If you delete twitter-bootstrap from CSS options tooltip is showing

Comment: i found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773470/bootstrap-css-breaks-tooltip-popover

Comment: thank you @ADyson your solution is working :)

Comment: Where does the element ````new Tooltip``` come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because [Bootstrap's CSS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css) includes rules relating to `.tooltip`. So there's a conflict between those CSS rules and the ones you've included for tooltip.js.

But bootstrap includes [its own tooltip functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/) which is also based on popper.js ....so if you're already using Bootstrap then you don't need tooltip.js on top, just use the Bootstrap ones.

Ensure you include

```
popper.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

in that order, and for CSS, remove your custom tooltip CSS and just include

```
bootstrap.min.css
```

in your page.

In the code, you can use all the same options for a Bootstrap tooltip as for tooltip.js (since they're both based on popper.js):

```
eventRender: function(info) {
  $(info.el).tooltip({ 
    title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
    placement: "top",
    trigger: "hover",
    container: "body"
  });
},
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/bPjgow

Comment: Absolutely the write answer. You have safe my life!