# tooltip in fullcalandar does not work with bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, tooltip, fullcalendar-4

Good morning,

My tooltip does not work if there is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`.

I have to remove this link for my tooltip to work.

Can you please help me?

Thank you very much for your help.

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'bootstrap'],
                defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
                defaultDate: '2020-05-12',
                

                eventRender: function (info) {
                    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                        title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                        placement: 'top',
                        trigger: 'hover',
                        container: 'body'
                    });
                },

                events: [{
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        description: 'description for All Day Event',
                        start: '2020-05-01'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        description: 'description for Long Event',
                        start: '2020-05-07',
                        end: '2020-05-10'
                    },
                    {
                        groupId: '999',
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        description: 'description for Repeating Event',
                        start: '2020-05-09T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        groupId: '999',
                        title: 'Repeating Event',
                        description: 'description for Repeating Event',
                        start: '2020-05-16T16:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Conference',
                        description: 'description for Conference',
                        start: '2020-05-11',
                        end: '2020-05-13'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        description: 'description for Meeting',
                        start: '2020-05-12T10:30:00',
                        end: '2020-05-12T12:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        description: 'description for Lunch',
                        start: '2020-05-12T12:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        description: 'description for Meeting',
                        start: '2020-05-12T14:30:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        description: 'description for Birthday Party',
                        start: '2020-05-13T07:00:00'
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        description: 'description for Click for Google',
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        start: '2020-05-28'
                    }
                ]
            });

            calendar.render();
        });
```

```css
 html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }

        .popper,
        .tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 9999;
            background: #FFC107;
            color: black;
            width: 150px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .style5 .tooltip {
            background: #1E252B;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            max-width: 200px;
            width: auto;
            font-size: .8rem;
            padding: .5em 1em;
        }

        .popper .popper__arrow,
        .tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            position: absolute;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .tooltip .tooltip-arrow,
        .popper .popper__arrow {
            border-color: #FFC107;
        }

        .style5 .tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
            border-color: #1E252B;
        }

        .popper[x-placement^="top"],
        .tooltip[x-placement^="top"] {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .popper[x-placement^="top"] .popper__arrow,
        .tooltip[x-placement^="top"] .tooltip-arrow {
            border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
            border-left-color: transparent;
            border-right-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: transparent;
            bottom: -5px;
            left: calc(50% - 5px);
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .popper[x-placement^="bottom"],
        .tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] {
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        .tooltip[x-placement^="bottom"] .tooltip-arrow,
        .popper[x-placement^="bottom"] .popper__arrow {
            border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            border-left-color: transparent;
            border-right-color: transparent;
            border-top-color: transparent;
            top: -5px;
            left: calc(50% - 5px);
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .tooltip[x-placement^="right"],
        .popper[x-placement^="right"] {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }

        .popper[x-placement^="right"] .popper__arrow,
        .tooltip[x-placement^="right"] .tooltip-arrow {
            border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
            border-left-color: transparent;
            border-top-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: transparent;
            left: -5px;
            top: calc(50% - 5px);
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        .popper[x-placement^="left"],
        .tooltip[x-placement^="left"] {
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .popper[x-placement^="left"] .popper__arrow,
        .tooltip[x-placement^="left"] .tooltip-arrow {
            border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
            border-top-color: transparent;
            border-right-color: transparent;
            border-bottom-color: transparent;
            right: -5px;
            top: calc(50% - 5px);
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-right: 0;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/list@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/bootstrap@4.4.0/main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/list@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/bootstrap@4.4.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js"></script> 
 
 
 
 
 
 <div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: You are linking to an OLD version of Bootstrap 4 CSS. Furthermore, Bootstrap 4 has its own tooltips.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried with the new link and it still does not work

Comment: You'll need to show what changes you made before we can help you further. "Does not work" isn't a useful description of the behaviour of your program

Comment: It's good i found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866108/tooltips-not-working-in-fullcalendar-when-i-use-bootstrap-css